# Google Map doesn't appear on the web page + InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-markers

using PHP & MYSQL on WordPress and Google Map API in order to retrieve data from MYSQL database and display markers with info windows on Google Map.

problem is that the map doesn't appear on the webpage, yet the SQL query is retrieving the required data.

what am i doing wrong and how to fix this Problem.

## code:

```
    <?php
        /*
        Template Name: search info_location
        */

        get_header();
          ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Markers</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**********&callback=initMap">
    </script>
     <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 600px;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>


  <?php
        // code for submit button action
        global $wpdb, $site_name;
    //variables that handle the retrieved data from mysql database based on the ID of the variable in HTML (select)



    if(isset($_POST['query_submit']))
    {


       if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
          { 
           $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];

          }
          else { $site_name=""; }


        if(isset($_POST['owner_name'])) 
         {
          $owner_name=$_POST['owner_name']; 

         } 
         else { $owner_name=""; }

         if(isset($_POST['Company_name'])) 
         {
          $company_name=$_POST['Company_name'];

         } 
         else { $company_name=""; }

        if(isset($_POST['Subcontractor_name'])) 
        { 
         $Subcontractor_name=$_POST['Subcontractor_name']; 

        }
        else { $Subcontractor_name="";}



 //   var_dump($site_name);

$sql = $wpdb->prepare("select i.siteID
     , i.siteNAME
     , i.equipmentTYPE
     , c.latitude
     , c.longitude
     , c.height 
     , o.ownerNAME
     , o.ownerCONTACT
     , x.companyNAME
     , y.subcontractorCOMPANY
     , y.subcontractorNAME
     , y.subcontractorCONTACT
  from site_info i
  LEFT  
  JOIN owner_info o
    on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
  LEFT  
  JOIN company_info x
    on i.companyID = x.companyID
  LEFT 
  JOIN subcontractor_info y
    on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
    LEFT JOIN site_coordinates2 c
    on i.siteID=c.siteID 
    where 
    i.siteNAME = %s
    AND 
    o.ownerNAME = %s
    AND 
    x.companyNAME = %s
   ",$site_name,$owner_name,$company_name);

 $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
//echo $sql;

//    var_dump($_POST['site_name']);

foreach ($query_submit as $obj) {



$obj->siteNAME;
$obj->ownerNAME;
$obj->companyNAME;
$obj->subcontractorNAME;
$obj->siteID;
$obj->equipmentTYPE;
$obj->latitude;
$obj->longitude;
$obj->height;
$obj->ownerCONTACT;
$obj->subcontractorCONTACT;
$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY;

    } 

// table that will dsiplay the results based on the user's selection //
   echo "<table width='30%' ";

echo     "<tr>";
echo           "<td>Site Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Owner Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Company Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Subcontractor Name</td>";
echo           "<td>Site ID</td>";
echo           "<td>Equipment Type</td>";
echo           "<td> Lattitude</td>";
echo           "<td>Longitude </td>";
echo           "<td> Height</td>";
echo           "<td> Owner Contact</td>";
echo           "<td> Sub Contact</td>";
echo           "<td> Sub company Name</td>";
echo   "</tr>";  
echo   "<tr>";        
echo         "<td>".$obj->siteNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->companyNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorNAME."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->siteID."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->equipmentTYPE."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->latitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->longitude."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->height."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->ownerCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCONTACT."</td>";
echo         "<td>".$obj->subcontractorCOMPANY."</td>";
echo  "</tr>";

echo  "<tr>";
echo     "<td>";

?>

<script>

     var map,currentPopup;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.888630, 35.495480),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var icons = {
          parking: {
            icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
          },
          library: {
            icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
          },
          info: {
            icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
          }
        };




        function addMarker(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,

            //icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
          });

          var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                   content: '<b>Site ID :</b> ' + feature.info +'<br></br>' 
                   + '<b> Site Name</b>' + feature.site_name +'<br></br>'  
                   + '<b>Coordinates :</b> '+ feature.position +'<br></br>' 
                   + '<b>height :</b> ' + feature.height,
                   maxWidth: 300
                });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    if (currentPopup != null) {
                        currentPopup.close();
                        currentPopup = null;
                    }
                    popup.open(map, marker);
                    currentPopup = popup;
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                    map.panTo(center);
                    currentPopup = null;
                });
        }



        var features = [
        <?php
            $prependStr ="";
            foreach( $wpdb->get_results("select c.siteID, c.latitude, c.longitude, c.height 
                                         , i.siteNAME
                                         FROM site_coordinates2 c LEFT 
                                         JOIN site_info i
                                         on c.siteID = i.siteID 
                                         where i.siteNAME = '".$site_name."'", OBJECT) as $key => $row) {
               $latitude = $row->latitude;
               $longitude = $row->longitude;
               $siteid = $row->siteID;
               $height = $row->height;
               $siteName = $row->siteNAME;
           echo $prependStr;
       ?>
{
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
    info:'<?php echo $siteid;?>',
    height: '<?php echo $height;?>',
    site_name: <?php echo $siteName;?>',

}
<?php
$prependStr =",";
}
?>
        ];



        for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {

          addMarker(feature);
        }
}

         </script>
 <?php        

echo     "</td>";     


echo  "</tr>";

echo "</table>";

 }

?>    

<!--  the below part  of code work as it should   --!>
    <!--create  dropdown list site names-->

    <form method ="post" action ="" name="submit_form">
        <table width="30%">
            <tr>
               <td>Site Name</td>
               <td>Owner Name</td>
               <td>Company Name</td>
               <td>Subcontractor Name</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">

                 <?php


                     $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results("select DISTINCT siteNAME  from site_info");
                      foreach($query_site_name as $site_name)
                      {
            //           $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                       echo "<option value = '".$site_name ->siteNAME."'>".  $site_name->siteNAME."</option>";
                      } 
                 ?>

                <!--create  dropdown list owner names-->
                </select></td>

                <td><select id="owner_name"  name ="owner_name">
                <?php
                 global $owner_name;
                      $query_owner_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT ownerNAME  from owner_info");
                      foreach($query_owner_name as $owner_name)
                      {
          //               $owner_name = (array)$owner_name;
                         echo "<option value = '".$owner_name->ownerNAME."'>".  $owner_name->ownerNAME."</option>";
                      } 
                  ?>
                </select></td>

                <!--create  dropdown list Company names-->
                </select></td>

                <td><select id="Company_name"  name ="Company_name">
                <?php 
                global $Company_name;
                     $query_Company_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT companyNAME  from company_info");
                     foreach($query_Company_name as $Company_name)
                     {
        //               $Company_name = (array)$Company_name;
                       echo "<option value = '".$Company_name->companyNAME."'>".  $Company_name->companyNAME."</option>";
                     }  
                 ?>
                </select></td>

                <!--create  dropdown list Subcontractor names-->
                </select></td>

                <td><select id="Subcontractor_name"  name ="Subcontractor_name">
                <?php 
                global $Subcontractor_name;
                    $query_Subcontractor_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT subcontractorNAME  from subcontractor_info");
                     foreach($query_Subcontractor_name as $Subcontractor_name)
                     {
      //                 $Subcontractor_name = (array)$Subcontractor_name;
                       echo "<option value = '".$Subcontractor_name->subcontractorNAME."}'>".  $Subcontractor_name->subcontractorNAME."</option>";
                      } 
                   ?>
                </select></td>
            <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <input type ="submit" name="query_submit" value ="Search" />

        </td>
       </tr>

        </table>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Are there errors in the console?

Comment: @tomudding no there is no error  the required data is retrieved but but displayed on the MAP (Google MAP doesn't appear)

Comment: Do you just need to add width to #map? hard to fully test